# Correct estimation of median, given sampled medians

Tags: estimation, median

I have a unit, which is a 'black box', which gives me `n` readouts `(X1, X2,..., Xn)` during one 'experiment'. I performed `N` such experiments. From each experiment, I have only a median of `X`. So I have `Med1, Med2,..., MedN`.

I want to estimate the median of X given `n->Inf`.

To complete this task I just average `Med1, Med2,..., MedN`.

**Is it a correct way? Or I should use another approach?**

Comment: Could you please explain what "given `n->Inf`" is intended to mean?  Are you asking how to estimate the median of the black box process $X$?

Comment: I want to now which median has a black box project if I would not be limited by n, but I would have an opportunity to observe the X infinite time.